# How To Make A WPF UserControl Act As A Container

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I'm trying to create a Toolbar control that can group selected buttons with a border and a label. If there is already a built-in control that will do this then I could use that instead of building a UserControl.

If not, then what I'm wanting to build is a UserControl that would allow me to enter one-to-many of my ImageButton UserControls and set a GroupLabel text like below.  Can this be done in WPF?

```
        <User_Controls:ToolbarGroup GroupLabel="Entity">
                <User_Controls:ImageButton ButtonText="Entity Setup"/>
                <User_Controls:ImageButton ButtonText="New Entity"/>
        </User_Controls:ToolbarGroup>
```

PS: I would post an image but this quirky forum won't allow me to post an image.

Comment: You can add a link to your image instead.

Answer (score 0):

If i have got you correctly then I think you can achieve this way also, and on mouse eneter and leave event you can do the button click job.
for setting text you can use a grid and a label inside it to set the text, and Image buttons below it.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ABC.View.Oats"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="Fill"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a GroupBox, it has a header property where you can set the label.

Something like this:

```
<GroupBox Width="300" Height="100">
        <GroupBox.Header>
            <Label>Text</Label>
        </GroupBox.Header>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Button"/>
            <Button Content="Button"/>
            <Button Content="Button"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend using the groupbox, it seems to be doing exactly what you want it to do and it looks neat. Here's some examples on how to use them: http://www.dotnetperls.com/groupbox-wpf

On the other hand, if you believe the groupbox is not sufficient, you could create a control that inherits from the groupbox and you could extend it and add whatever you need to it. It would look like this:

```
public class customGroupBox: GroupBox{
 ....Add whatever you need here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies.  I tried the GroupBox and it's not the layout we want because we want the label underneath the buttons and centered.  I never could find a way to add a collection to the UserControl.  Maybe I didn't ask the question right by calling it a container.  The code below will work, but it's not elegant.  I wanted something that would wrap the layout in a UserControl and allow me to add a variable number of buttons to each toolbar group.

```html
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Border Background="GhostWhite" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="1">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <User_Controls:ImageButton ButtonText="New 1"/>
                        <User_Controls:ImageButton ButtonText="New 2"/>
                        <User_Controls:ImageButton ButtonText="New 3"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Group 1"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
            <Border Background="GhostWhite" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="1">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <User_Controls:ImageButton ButtonText="New 4"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Group 2"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is with a custom styled ItemsControl.

You can then reuse it and just bind it to different data.

Please forgive me, this is hand-typed...

In your resources...

```
<Style x:Key="ToolbarGroupItemsControlStyle" TargetType="ItemsControl">
    ...
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                <Grid>
                    ... XAML to form your group with a binding to the
                    ... group name
                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ToolbarGroupItemTemplate">
    <Grid>
        ... XAML and binding for each toolbar group item ...
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

In your XAML...

```
<ItemsControl 
    Style="{DynamicResource ToolbarGroupItemsControlStyle}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ToolbarGroupItems}"
    ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ToolbarGroupItemTemplate"/>
```

If your resources above are at the application level, then you can place the ItemsControl above on any Window/UserControl you want.

Your ItemsSource will need to be a collection of a custom type you create that has bindings for the button text, etc.

I hope this is helpful.